# Doctrine/dbal - Got error when try to change a string field to date

Tags: laravel, doctrine, dbal

I created a table using a Laravel migration. I migrated two fields as strings but I want one as the date and one as an integer. So I created a new migration for changing those fields. I installed doctrine/dbal. I use Laravel 6.5. However, I got an error when trying to migrate.

**Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('follow_up_task', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->date('next_follow_date')->change();
        $table->integer('follow_stop_after')->change();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('follow_up_task', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('next_follow_date')->change();
        $table->string('follow_stop_after')->change();
    });
}
```

But I got an error.

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, CHANGE recurrin' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE recurring_tasks CHANGE next_recurring_date next_recurring_date DATE CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, CHANGE recurring_stop_after recurring_stop_after INT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`)

```
at /home/vagrant/laravel-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
668|         catch (Exception $e) {
669|             throw new QueryException(
670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
671|             );
672|         }
673| 

Exception trace:
```

1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, CHANGE recurrin' at line 1")
      /home/vagrant/laravel-api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:63

2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, CHANGE recurrin' at line 1")
      /home/vagrant/laravel-api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:61

Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Comment: Add doctrine/dbal dependency to composer.json for more information you can find it here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#modifying-columns

Comment: I already added doctrine/dbal dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then it could be because of bug in the most recent version of the `doctrine/dbal` `v2.10.0` package.

You can downgrade your `doctrine/dbal` package in `composer.json` to `v2.9.3`.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30539#issuecomment-559605145

You can try to use raw sql query in migration `up()` like this.

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE .....");
```

Answer (score 2):

Also we can use

```
$table->date('next_follow_date')->charset('')->collation('')->change();
```

for avoid this problem